# How to fix cracked minifig arms?

Tags: piece-information, minifigures, repair

I have a few minifigs with their arms cracked lengthwise, which is a big problem as the hands constantly fall off at the slightest touch (or even fall off of their own accord). Is there any way to fix this? Sorry for any inconvenience, but I don't know how to put a picture up. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

### Arms are cheap

I'd recommend just buying some cheap replacements from a site like [BrickLink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page). You can buy an unpainted torso for example, and some sellers even sell just [the](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=982) [arms](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=981) (some of the cheapest listings are described as cracked though, so avoid those). So long as the arm is not painted (which they are not usually), this should be a relatively cheap solution with no repair work besides swapping the arms.

Plus, considering how small they are I'm not really sure there is a practical way to repair them, and still retain their full function.

Comment: I think a minuscule amount of thin glue dropped into or onto the crack (with the hands removed of course) would provide the necessary amount of adhesion, but I haven't had the necessity to test it yet.